# How to silence gem errors after switching to bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I recently switched to using bundler and now anytime I run a script under the scripts/ folder in my rails app I get the following warning:

```
config.gem: Unpacked gem environment.rb in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
config.gem: Unpacked gem environment.rb in vendor/gems not in a versioned directory. Giving up.
config.gem: Unpacked gem ruby in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
config.gem: Unpacked gem ruby in vendor/gems not in a versioned directory. Giving up.
```

What do I have to do to silence these errors or resolve them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem today. Go to config/environment.rb and add the following line within the config block.

```
Rails::VendorGemSourceIndex.silence_spec_warnings = true
```